# DD-WRT Linksys WRT320N Max Tx Power

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

What is the save max Tx Power setting for WRT320N in DD-WRT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, by experience (I am running this router with DD-WRT for about two weeks now), it is around 150mW.

Comment: The old WRT54GS was 100 mW, but I believe with third-party firmware you could crank it up to 150 mW (the waveform got sloppy if you did that, though). So, this sounds about right.

Answer (score 1):

I find that even at the stock 70 mW (or whatever it is) it starts to just stop working and requires a restart. I've been dialing it back to around 45mW and that seems to work. It is also very well ventilated, fyi.

Answer (score -1):

This wireless dual band router has a max TX rate of 270 mpbs.

> **MAX. TX RATE**  - 270 Mbps
>
> **MAX. DISTANCE** -
>
> **WIRELESS STANDARD** 802.11a,802.11b,802.11g,802.11n,

http://www.itbankeurope.com/WRT320N-EE_/

Comment: No, no ... I was wondering about "Tx power" setting in DD-WRT firmware - transmitting power in [mW].